# How to convert react element to HTML

Tags: reactjs

Usage of TestComponent

```
 <TestComponent
   testContent= {
     <div>
       <p>sometxt <a href="#">link1</a><p>
       <p>hello how was your day</p>
       <p>some other txt <a href="#">link1</a><p>
     </div>
   }
 />

class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    const testContent = props.testContent;
  }
}
```

In the above component code,In constructor, when i try to access props.testContent. It's type is react element. However i want to query the content to find the focusable elements e:g:  in this example. As the prop value is react element querySelector() can not be used. so i need to covert this react element to HTML element.

Could any one help me to know how can i achieve this.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your example, there isn't yet an HTML element (aka DOM Node) - this won't exist until the component has been mounted into the DOM. Once that's done you can either use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()` (See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) or a `ref` (See https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to access the element.

You would need to do this step in either the `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` React lifecycle methods. (See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right @ReactDOM.findDOMNode() is useful once the component is mounted into the DOM. However here i want to query from the props value to get the fousable elements inside the constructor, which is before mounting into the DOM. Is there any you could suggest. Thanks!

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to use a library like this one: https://github.com/Olical/react-faux-dom that provides a "DOM-like" structure. It might let you do what you need.